# Use an external sprite or image file in flixel game in flashbuilder

Tags: sprites, actionscript-3, spritesheet, flixel

Is there any way to use an external image/sprite file for the graphic of a FlxSprite instance?

Say I declare my player FlxSprite as follows:

```
player = new FlxSprite(FlxG.width/2 - 5);
player.makeGraphic(10,12,0xffaa1111);
```

How could I instead instantiate the FlxSprite using my own spritesheet or image?
I have seen others do it in the Flixel [demos](http://flixel.org/features.html) , and in the featured games.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the loadGraphic method of FlxSprite, here's an example :

```
// in your class declarations 
[Embed(source="your.png")] private var yourGraphic:Class;

// in your class code wherever, after you have created an instance
// use true for second parameter if image is a row of sprite frames
player.loadGraphic(yourGraphic, false);
```